# Hibernate/JPA Only Displays Select Statements. Update/Delete Statements Are Skipped And There Are No Errors In The Console

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, db2

We are using Hibernate/JPA and our Delete/Update calls work in the standalone JAR. However, in the WAR, only SELECT statements are shown, and the Delete/Update queries are completely skipped over. They are nowhere to be seen. There are no errors in the console too and we get the returned id.

We have added @Transactional to our service layer and @Modifying to our repository as well.

Has anyone ever encountered something like this?

EDIT: This is not an issue about our logger or ProfileLogger. This is an issue where DELETE/UPDATE statements are not even being triggered by hibernate/jpa within our WAR, but works within our standalone jar. Can this have anything to do with our transactions?

## DAO

```
@Repository
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbObjEntityManagerFactory")
public class DeleteDbObjDaoImpl implements DeleteDbObjDao {

private static final String LOGGING_CLASS = 
"DeleteDataObjDetailsDaoImpl";

@Autowired
private ProfileLogger logger;

@Autowired
Repo1   repo1;

@Autowired
Repo2 repo2;

@Autowired
Repo3 repo3;

@Autowired
Repo4 repo4;


@Override
public DbObjInfo deleteDbObjDetails(String id1, String id2, String id3, 
String id4){

    String LOGGING_METHOD = "deleteItemFromDb";
    logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, DeleteItemConstant.ENTRY+" For USERID 
"+userId, LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS,
            LOGGING_METHOD, null);

    DbOjbInfo dbObjInfo = getDbObjDao.getDbObjDetails(id1, id2, id3, id4);

    try {
        deleteDataObj.deleteBySourceAcctNo(id1);
    }
    catch(DeleteDataObjSvcDBException e){
        logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, DeleteItemContant.EXIT+" For 
USERID "+userId, LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS,
                LOGGING_METHOD, null);
        throw new DeleteItemSvcException(e.getDescription());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, "Error while deleting data for 
DbOjb # " + id1 +" from database "+" For USERID "+userId+ "  Error Message 
is "+e.getMessage(),
                LoggerLevel.ERROR, LOGGING_CLASS, LOGGING_METHOD, null);
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, DeleteDataObj.EXIT, 
LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS,
                LOGGING_METHOD, null);
        throw new DeleteDataObjSvcDBException(DeleteDataObjConstants.DATA_OBJ_DB_DELETE_FAILED);
    }

    logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, DeleteDbDataObjConstants.EXIT+" For USERID "+userId, LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS,
            LOGGING_METHOD, null);
    return dbObjInfo;
}
```

## SERVICE

```
@Service
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbDataObjEntityManagerFactory")
public class DataObjDeleteServiceImpl implements DataObjDeleteService {

private static final String LOGGING_CLASS = "DataObjDeleteServiceImpl";

@Autowired
private ProfileLogger logger;

@Autowired
DeleteDataObjDao deleteDataObjDetailsDao;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackForClassName = {
        "Exception"})private String deleteDataObj(String id1, String id2, String id3,
                                                     String id4) {

    String LOGGING_METHOD = "deleteDataObj";
    logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, DeleteDataObjConstants.ENTRY+" For USERID "+id1, LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS,
            LOGGING_METHOD, null);
    DataObjInfo dataObjInfo = null;
    logger.writeToTraceLog(sessionId, "Deleting for dataObj # " + id,
            LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS, LOGGING_METHOD, null);
    ResponseEntity<AccountAuditInfo> responseEntity = null;

    try{
        DeleteDataObj deleteDataObj =
                deleteDataObjDetailsDao.deleteDbObjDetails(id1, id2, id3, id4);
        }

    }
    catch (DeleteDataObjSvcDBException ex) {
        throw new DeleteDataObjSvcSystemException(objErrorVOList);
    }
    logger.writeToTraceLog(id, DeleteDataObjConstants.EXIT+" For USERID "+id, LoggerLevel.INFO, LOGGING_CLASS,
            LOGGING_METHOD, null);
    return id;
}
```

## CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/associates/{dbObjId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteDbObj(
        @PathVariable("dbObjId") String id,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Request-ID", required = false, defaultValue = "") String id2,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Consumer-Id", required = false, defaultValue = "") String id3)

        ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
        String LOGGING_METHOD = "deleteDbObj";
        String id4 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        response = dataObjDeleteService.deleteDataObjDetails(id, id2, id3, id4);
        return response;
    }
```

## CONSOLE

```
15:37:26,077 INFO  [org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.ScannerModule] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) using FIELD mappingStyle
15:37:26,077 INFO  [org.javers.core.JaversBuilder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) loading GuavaAddOns ...
15:37:26,078 INFO  [org.javers.core.JaversBuilder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) loading JodaAddOns ...
15:37:26,079 INFO  [org.javers.core.JaversBuilder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) using fake InMemoryRepository, registerType actual implementation via JaversBuilder.registerJaversRepository()
15:37:26,079 INFO  [org.javers.core.JaversBuilder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) JaVers instance started in 2 ms
15:37:26,080 INFO  [TraceLogger] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) dbff0d61-36d5-4f1b-a2d8-d2f0895cd604[DeleteDataObjDaoImpl-deleteDbObjDetails]Entry
15:37:26,081 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) Hibernate: select entty1.entty1_ID as assoc1_en1_14_, t111assoc0_.assoc_name as entt2_AL2_14_, entt3.ASSOC_BIRTH_CITY_NM as ASSOC_entty3_, entty2.ASSOC_BIRTH_CTZN_CTRY_ID as assoc_entty2_BI4_14_, entty2.assoc_entty_birth as assoc_entty_10_11, entty2.assoc_entty_date as assoc_entty_ca2
15:37:26,273 INFO  [TraceLogger] (http-/127.0.0.1:8179-1) dbff0d61-36d5-4f1b-a2d8-d2f0895cd604[DbDataObjServiceImpl-deleteDataObj]Exit For ID
```

## JPA Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbObjEntityManagerFactory")
public interface dbObjRepository extends JpaRepository<dbObj, Integer>{

  dbObj findBySourceAcctNo(String sourceAcctNo);

 /* String deleteBySourceAcctNo(String id);*/

  @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query(value = "delete from dbObjEntty a where a.sourceAcctNo =?1")
  void deleteBySourceAcctNo(String sourceAcctNo);


}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with a "real database"/the data? ...because you only complain about logging ..and use a "fake database". And what is this `ProfileLogger` ... `org.apache.tools.ant.listener`?

Comment: That's not a stack trace, it's the console log. How is your logging configured?

Comment: @xerx593 The data is completely fine. Using the same data in the single jar everything works. It’s within the war where this happened, where there are other apis. It’s strange because we use some Stores Procs that update data so I know the database is working and there would be an error thrown if the data was wrong. I feel it has something to do with hibernate and transactions not being set up correctly maybe?

Comment: @OakDawg Please confirm - data is ok! (in jar and war scenario?) ...then it's "just" a logging issue. (in ".war scenario" only) ?

Comment: ..when so, the logging issue might be trivial(1.): configured log level (in .war) is not "low enough" (1a.) (for `TRACE` ...since you `writeToTraceLog()`) ...or you are "just" looking into the "wrong place" (1b.) (output/file/console). ;) ..if it's not that trivial (2.), then you/we'd need deeper understanding of `ProfileLogger`. ..and details about your "runtime".

Comment: Thing is, the delete/update calls are not being executed in the WAR. In the jar changes are being seen in the database, with the same exact delete call. dao.deleteDetails or dao.updateDetails .

Comment: This is not an issue about logging, forget the ProfileLogger. This is an issue about DB calls not actually executing in the WAR but working in the JAR. Only select calls are executed by hibernate in the WAR